# Recovering deleted files using php

Tags: php, data-recovery, file-recovery

I honestly don't know what I did. But I used either `rmdir()` or `unlink()` and accidentally deleted some files I worked on today.

I am using Mac OS X

PLEASE PLEASE tell me there is someway I can any of them back. I am open to any suggestions.

It literally **just** happened.

Comment: You deleted before I could modify my comment but do you use an IDE? Some have a local file history as well, I know NetBeans does.

Comment: I am using Sublime so I don't think so :(

Comment: Don't know Sublime, but you should check if it maintains a local file history. Otherwise no experience with Mac...

Comment: It doesn't @jeroen but thank you.

Comment: first rule when you want to recover deleted files, is to turn the computer off immediately, and do not boot to that drive again until they are recovered. you may have some luck with photorec, or check this out: http://www.cultofmac.com/67472/how-to-undelete-files-in-mac-os-x-macrx/ using the computer can cause the files to be overwritten at which point they are unrecoverable.